# Select returns "¿" character

Tags: database, oracle, character-set

My query:

```
SELECT op_arv
FROM my_table@OTHER_DB
```

returns:

```
d¿identification
```

The "¿" symbol should not be there.

If I then run:

```
SELECT 
 substr(op_arv,2,1) AS t_substr
,ascii(substr(op_arv,2,1)) AS t_ascii
,chr(ascii(substr(op_arv,2,1))) AS t_chr_ascii
,asciistr(substr(op_arv,2,1)) AS asciistr_1
FROM my_table@OTHER_DB
```

I get the following output:

```
¿
146
¿
\0092
```

The ASCII function returns 146, which corresponds to the **’** (apostrophe) symbol which makes sense. But if I try to "CHR()" the actual value, I will get **¿** instead of **’**. CHR(146) gives me the correct symbol...

Running ASCIISTR function will return the Unicode value \0092 which is a unicode control character, not an apostrophe...

I am running Oracle 11gR2 with NLS_CHARACTERSET= WE8MSWIN1252. I am connecting (through a database link) to an Oracle database running with NLS_CHARACTERSET= WE8ISO8859P1.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: The asciistr result is in hex; and 92 in base-16 is 146 in base-10, so that does match.  What is your *client* characterset - e.g. from your NLS_LANG setting if you're using SQL\*Plus (I'd guess US7ASCII); and your OS/shell/emulatar encoding? This looks like a client rendering issue, not a data or DB problem.

Comment: Which tool do you use to run the select statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely  you did not set your `NLS_LANG` value and Oracle defaults it to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.US7ASCII`.

SQLplus inherits the character set from command line, you can interrogate/change the codepage with command `chcp` and then you must set `NLS_LANG` accordingly.

Example:

```
chcp 1252
set NLS_LANG=.WE8MSWIN1252
sqlplus ...
```

If you work on Linux then use `locale charmap` or `echo $LANG` to retrieve the encoding of your terminal.

It is not required to set `NLS_LANG` equal to your database character set, however the character set you choose must support your character `’`